# I can't run Hive from Mac terminal

Tags: hadoop, hive

I downloaded Hive and Hadoop onto my system, when I enter the jps command all the nodes seem to be running:

```
81699 SecondaryNameNode
65058 ResourceManager
82039 NodeManager
36086 
81463 NameNode
91288 Jps
37193 Launcher
95256 Launcher
81563 DataNode
```

However when I try to run hive using the ./hive command I get the following error:

```
WARNING: log4j.properties is not found. HADOOP_CONF_DIR may be incomplete.
ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_COMMON_HOME
Unable to determine Hadoop version information.
'hadoop version' returned:
WARNING: log4j.properties is not found. HADOOP_CONF_DIR may be incomplete.
ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_COMMON_HOME
```

This is what my ~/.bashrc file looks like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_311.jdk
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.1

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/etc/hadoop

export HIVE_HOME=/Users/arjunpanyam/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

Comment: As the error says, you have no `HADOOP_COMMON_HOME`. Latest Mac's use `~/.zshrc`, by the way. Did you source your bashrc into that?

Comment: You'll also want to create a proper `log4j.properties` file in your Hadoop installation folders so that you get more descriptive logs

Comment: @OneCricketeer How would I go about sourcing the bash file to ~/.zshrc?

Comment: Either you can move all these variables to that file, or you can simply `source ~/.bashrc` into the `~/.zshrc`

Comment: @OneCricketeer After adding a HADOOP_COMMON_HOME row and executing this command: source ~/.bashrc I am getting the following error: Unable to determine Hadoop version information.
'hadoop version' returned:

Comment: Okay, well, you can always run `hadoop version` yourself to see its output. But like I said, adding a log4j file instead of the default template file would help debug further

Comment: @OneCricketeer the 'hadoop version' command doesn't return anything for some reason

Comment: Yes. And that is the error that Hive is complaining about. So, seems like something with the Hadoop installation itself is not correct.